# Posição XY em C, reposicionamento

Tags: c, coordenadas

Pessoal estou necessitando das coordenadas atuais "cursor" da tela, para que o usuário permaneça na linha atual.

#### EXEMPLO

```
void main{

    char nome[50];
    char sobrenome[50];

    int linhaAtual;
    linhaAtual = ????;
    
    gotoxy(1, linhaAtual);
    printf("Insira seu nome:");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", nome);
    
    gotoxy(1, linhaAtual);
    printf("Insira seu sobrenome:");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", nome);
    
    system("pause");
}
```

#### OBS

No exemplo não estou levando em considerando a necessidade de limpar toda linha. Irei desenvolver.

#### PESQUISAS

propriedade `wherex()` , `wherey()`   -  não funciona, não sei por que motivo.
propriedade `__LINE__`  - aparentemente a contagem é diferente.

Comment: Ainda bem que `__LINE__` não deu certo. Você já pensou porque só existe a linha e não a coluna nisto? Vamos ao que está relacionado ao que você quer: porque o `where?()` não funciona? Se você que fez a aplicação não sabe o motivo, nós sabemos menos ainda. Você não colocou o `#include` que está usando. Isto é importante. Espero que não esteja usando o `conio.h`, isto não faz parte do padrão e está obsoleto.

Comment: @guilherme-lautert Para você, **ponteiro** = **cursor**? Edita a pergunta e ajusta esse detalhe, faz bastante diferença.

Comment: @bigown, fiquei curioso com "Ainda bem que `__LINE__` não deu certo." e pesquisando chegando a isto: http://www.lemoda.net/c/line-file-func/
Muito interessante, na minha pesquisa anterior `__LINE__`, foi apontado como posição da coordenada y, só não foi mencionado "do arquivo".
Quanto ao `#include conio.h`, na verdade é exatamente o que estou usando, estou ciente da existência do `conio2.h`, contudo achei que poderia existir alguma propriedade paterna no próprio C.

Comment: @karlphillip eu sei que *ponteiro != cursor*, mas tecnicamente também não encaro `|` de linha como um cursor. Não conseguiu me expressar corretamente na hora.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Eu te entendo, mas quando queremos ajuda da comunidade temos que utilizar os termos técnicos que fazem parte da terminologia da área, senão corremos o risco de não sermos entendidos. Se **cursor** é um nome apropriado ou não para definir esta funcionalidade eu não sei, mas os livros, manuais e documentações se referem a ela por este nome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está se referindo à funções do *header* `conio.h` (criado para apps de linha de comando no Windows). Esse *header* não faz parte da biblioteca padrão da linguagem C, e são poucos compiladores que suportam ele nativamente.

O que acontece é que ao rodar sua aplicação em IDEs como *Qt Creator*, ou outros que possuam um console próprio, não existem garantias de que essas funções irão funcionar. O melhor é usar um compilador que suporta nativamente o `conio.h`, e depois rodar seu aplicativo diretamente do *Command Prompt* do Windows (**cmd.exe**).

Bem, dizer que algo "não funciona" é bastante vago, então eu vou assumir que você não teve problemas de compilação ou linkagem com essa biblioteca.

Se você seguiu as orientações acima, de acordo com a documentação, invocar as funções abaixo:

```
int x = wherex();
int y = wherey();
printf("x: %d  y:%d\n", x, y);
```

irá imprimir na tela a posição (X,Y) do cursor.

Comment: creio que minha IDE possui a `conio.h`, mas não a rode corretamente como você comentou, pois eu possui o `#include conio.h` e estes comandos apresentam erro quanto utilizados.

Comment: Agora chegamos ao ponto: qual é o **erro**? Seja bem específico, por favor, senão não poderemos te ajudar.

Comment: Então o que acontece quando você imprime `x` e `y` na tela? Quais são os valores deles?

Comment: como citei no no comentário para o @bigown, tive de usar a biblioteca `conio2.h`, pois a minha atual `conio.h` não possui estas funções, assim quando tento compilar ele exibe `where?() not declared in this scope`.